# Select max of count from a table and update another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

[image]

I need to find the max value base on Count from column col1_class and update table2 column 'lbl1' with the value
I tried  this code but i gets error:

```
update testClassLable
set lbl1 = (
    select max(maxVal)
    from (
        select count (col1_class) as maxVal
        from tbl_test_all
        group by col1_class
    )x
)
```

can you help please?

*** UPDATE ***

I edited the code above and its work now but it return :

0 row(s) affected !

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Why does your query not contain the table `table2`?

Comment: Maybe you need to add "AS temp" or another temp-table name after you inner end parentheses to give the temporary table a name

Comment: I edited  the code now it says 0 row affected

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
update testClassLable
set lbl1 = (
    select max(countVal)
    from (
        select count(col1_class) as countVal
        from tbl_test_all
        group by col1_class
    ) x
)
```

Comment: And if i put "AS maxVal" instead of "AS countVal" it works but it returns 0 row affected!

Comment: @meysammotamedi yes it was a typo, run only select statement part and see what is the result

Comment: @meysammotamedi Because there is no row in your testClassLable table, first insert a row for example manually (a 0 or null) then run the command, it will work